# Sistema de cadastro de usuário

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu já tenho o sistema, só que não sei desenvolver os erros.
Por exemplo: Senhas não coincidem, usuário já existe, email já existe.

```
    <?php

include('../includes/config.php');

$usuario    = $_POST ["usuario"];   
$email  = $_POST ["email"];
$senha = MD5($_POST["senha"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `usuario` , `email`, `senha`, `usuario_id` ) 
VALUES ('$usuario', '$email', '$senha', '')";

mysql_query($query);

echo "";

?>
```

E um formulário:

```
    <form action="registrar.php" method="post">
    <input name="usuario" type="text" id="usuario"><br>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email"><br>
    <input name="senha" type="password" id="senha">
    <input name="senha2" type="password" id="senha2">
    </form>
```

O sistema já funciona, já cadastra e tudo, só faltam os erros. E queria que aparecesse uma script do navegador com o erro escrito.

Answer (score 0):

Bem isso e mais simples do que parece, basta passar os erros para a $_SESSION,
e apresenta-los na zona de registo.
tem que comecar o seu codigo com `session_start();`

```
<?php
session_start();
// balbalbal mais codigo qualquer aqui

?>
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['erros']))
    {
   foreach($_SESSION['erros'] as $erro)
    {
        echo "<h2>$erro</h2>";
    }
    }
?>
<form action="registrar.php" method="post">
    <input name="usuario" type="text" id="usuario"><br>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email"><br>
    <input name="senha" type="password" id="senha">
    <input name="senha2" type="password" id="senha2">
    </form>
```

Na zona de tentar fazer o registo

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['erros'] = "";
$erros = array();
$i = 0;
// Quando o utilizador tiver algum erro basta adicionar isto
$i++;
$erros[$i] = "Erro nao sei qual.";

// No fim da detencao dos erros basta meter isto
$_SESSION['erros'] = $erros;
header("Location: register.php"); // Nao sei se o ficheiro para registar e esse mas vou tentar adivinhar xD
```